# how to find a localhost using a django server to contact with android device?

Tags: android, django, request, localhost

I've set up a Django server on ubuntu and I want to get JSON data from it and show them on an android device but I don't know the server name.
I tried 10.0.2.2, localhost, 127.0.0.1 and ip address but none of them worked. like:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet method = new HttpGet("http://localhost:8000/books/4/?format=json");
            try {
                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(method);
                InputStream is = response.getEntity().getContent();
                content[0] = IStoString(is);
                Log.i("SERVERTEST", content[0]);
            } catch (ClientProtocolException r) {
                r.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });
    thread.start();
```

the code works with other APIs.

> The Exception is: connection to http://127.0.0.1:8000 refused

Answer (score 0):

when I test with android device, I do these steps:
1. open device wifi hot spot
2. connect Ubuntu server to device's wifi
3. in Ubuntu terminal, run ifconfig to get IP address
4. run web server on Ubuntu
5. connect from device using IP address from step 3

But I found that I will need to open data connection on the device too, not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some of these services that will provide a tunnel to your localhost and provide you an externally available URL even with `https`.

- http://localtunnel.me/
- https://ngrok.com/

So if you have `http://127.0.0.1:8000/my_endpoint`
It will be available as `https://{provided_url}/my_enpoint` from the internet.